# How can I write SOS with 11 chances?

Tags: the-silent-sea-moon-escape

I have 11 chances to turn red circles into green. What I need to write down with the circles is SOS. The morse code for SOS is `..._ _ _ ...`, how can I express "SOS" here with 11 circles?

[image: you can turn max. 11 red circles into green]

Answer (score 10):

Simply write "S O S" by turning 11 squares green:

[image]

Comment: An explanation would be welcome as to how this counts as "writing SOS."

Comment: @Tom  if you look at all the red fields left, it literally spells "S O S"