# What game is being asked about in "How can I write SOS with 11 chances?"

Tags: game-identification

The question [How can I write SOS with 11 chances?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/394171/how-can-i-write-sos-with-11-chances), despite being tagged [the-impossible-quiz](/questions/tagged/the-impossible-quiz), is clearly not about [The Impossible Quiz](https://impossible-quiz.fandom.com/wiki/The_Impossible_Quiz). It includes this screenshot:

[image: you can turn max. 11 red circles into green]

So, what game is this about?

Comment: I found [this page](https://page.onstove.com/epicseven/kr/view/8082390) in Korean talking about the same game, but based on google translate it doesn't look like they mention the name anywhere (it's tagged "Epic Seven" but that seems to be unrelated)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is from [The Silent Sea - Moon Escape](https://thesilentsea.net/index_en.html)

It's a puzzle game that is a promo tie in for the Korean Netflix series [The Silent Sea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Silent_Sea_(TV_series))

[image]

I found it by doing reverse image search on all of the "inventory" assets and found it with [this one](https://www.google.com/search?tbs=sbi:AMhZZitKUjSp3scZoVTSljhoauwYLkxlUvTnSf-e-_1u-tkn73WjmtU2iWvr2SMQsTsknR6FLOsCqTwVoMciK1OuSUYlA2GHRORVdt1RvtVOIYTmfdrZ8jp3zQfIIStCbo84d7OArbxKP21lVm3IA-mpQQ2p_1fdENQx3yE875j4o8J81NnStEBcPZPbgHk0Ph53IpnuVk1HxIjAWBhKud0iEDHx4oo6OS40zIOOxRAdbFaekvGv2iwL2kQfXhXdqVgx83O5Y_1d7n-RSIv1p2F4mMP2ea_1XeKBJDuQ0GNKNi-JEuB0GsRIKGn2aZpF02B4KZSdyyPAEKcZJN8MEd8nA62bw0TOXju5yQ):

[image]

Without giving any spoilers to solving the puzzle, the sos room is the 2nd room of Storage 5.

The game lets you pick b/t Korean and English.